# ForeColor for UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

Very short question, but can anyone tell me what the property `ForeColor` does in a WinForms `User Control`?

I Have tried to look in the (slightly) confusion documentation, and tried to fiddle around with it myself, but with no luck.

**Clarification:** I am talking about a Windows Forms User Control, as in the re-usable control you can create. Not the generic meaning of a control.

Comment: It's a common property derived from `Control`. For most controls it sets text color for control. In a `UserControl`, if you don't set a `ForeColor` for child controls of your `UserControl`,  they will use their parent's `ForeColor`. Also if you want to customize rendering of your control, you can use its value for rendering text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common property derived from [`Control`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,039c1952b93309f7). For most controls it sets text color for control.

In a `UserControl`, if you don't set a `ForeColor` for child controls of your `UserControl`,  they will use their parent's `ForeColor`. Also if you want to customize rendering of your control, you can use its value for rendering text.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's the text etc.  IE forecolor black, is black text.

Comment: This would also explain what the `Font` properties is good for. However, I cannot see any `Text` property of a user control?

Comment: Well it depends on the control.. it's an object, maybe inherent from a textbox or label?

Comment: I mean a user control does only what it's programmed to... not sure I'm explaining this that well.

Comment: I think it is me, who hasn't been clear enough. Sorry. I meant the re-usable class User Control, which you create in a project. Not the standard components you can drag and drop. For anything which contains an actual `Text` property, I can easily see the effect.

Comment: No, we are discussing the same thing, but the property must be implemented.  A usercontrol is nothing until you hook up the events and properties.

Answer (score 0):

`ForeColor` Simply changes in most controls the color of the Text.

It comes from the `Control` Class and has the default of `DefaultForeColor`

Which if there is a parent control refers to the parents `ForeColor`

```
Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue;
```

[image]

Or for example:

```
Label1.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
Label1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the re-usable class Windows User Control, not the generic term control.

Comment: you mean Control.ForeColor?

Comment: See the accepted answer, I think that will make it clear :-)

Comment: yeah thats what I had edited simply check the msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx